# how to connect hive in secure mode(kerberos+ssl) using JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I need to connect hive(kerberos + SSL) using jdbc, i tried this code but getting error like :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/VersionInfo
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopThriftAuthBridge(ShimLoader.java:120)
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.HttpAuthUtils.getKerberosServiceTicket(HttpAuthUtils.java:52)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HttpKerberosRequestInterceptor.process(HttpKerberosRequestInterceptor.java:63)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:109)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:176)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:518)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:827)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flushUsingHttpClient(THttpClient.java:235)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flush(THttpClient.java:297)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:65)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.send_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:141)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:133)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createHttpTransport(HiveConnection.java:267)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:201)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:168)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at prodhive.main(prod_test.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        System.out.println("Driver Registered");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception Occured");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("before connection");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            ("jdbc:hive2://abc.xyz.com:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@XYZ.COM;KrbRealm=PQR.COM;KrbHostFQDN=abc.xyz.com;KrbServiceName=hive;KrbAuthType=0;SSLKeyStore=/home/arcosadmin/va.xyz.com.jks;SSLKeyStorePwd=1234;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;SSL=1;AuthMech=3;UID=HS2;PWD=1234")

    System.out.println("Connection Established Successfully");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Table Creation Started");
    String tableName = "hive_con";
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + "(eid int, name String,destination String)");
    System.out.println("Table have been created");
    con.close();
    System.out.println("Connection Closed");

}
```

Comment: You do not even handle Kerberos in your code. Check here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189866/hive-jdbc-kerberos-connectivity-error

Comment: i used this ("jdbc:hive2://abc.xyz.com:10000/default;KrbRealm=ABC.COM;KrbHostFQDN=abc.xyz.com;KrbServiceName=hive;KrbAuthType=0;SSLKeyStore=/home/admin/abcva.xyz.com.jks;SSLKeyStorePwd=1234;SSL=1;AuthMech=3") --- got this error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/common/auth/HiveAuthUtils

Comment: Seems to be a library problem. You need to use the Hive jar provided with your distribution (HDP, CDH, .)